# How do I change the dataset of gridView from menu android

Tags: android, gridview

I have a `GridView` which is populated by some images ( lets say bird images ), so now I want to change the data of that view to show ( mammal images ) when i click the menu item, how do i do that ?

I have those images as arrays like this :

```
private int[] birdImage = { 

            R.drawable.huuhkaja, 
            R.drawable.peippo,
            R.drawable.peukaloinen, 
            R.drawable.punatulkku,

    };
    private int[] mammalImage = {

    R.drawable.bear, 
    R.drawable.elephant, 
    R.drawable.wolf, 
    R.drawable.lamb,

    };
```

Answer (score 0):

From the menu I would:

```
putExtra("img_type", "bird");
```

depending on which item clickd and then in the gridview activity I would get the extra and use a if statement like:

```
  if(img_type.equals("bird")) {
            code here to use the bird images, etc
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add menu item like this..

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        menu.add(0, 1, Menu.NONE,"birds");
        menu.add(0, 2, Menu.NONE,"mammals");
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

After Adding this two menu item in onOptionItemSelected method you can set griview data as you wish..

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case 1:

                    **// here code for seting birds data**
            break;

        case 2:
             **// here code for seting mammals data**
            break;

        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```